# Why are my arrow keys getting stuck? CodeRush/VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coderush-xpress

I have VS2010 and CodeRush Express installed on my machine. Occasionally I am hitting some key combination (inadvertently, don't know what I am hitting) that is causing my up/down arrow keys to get "stuck", they stop moving the cursor up and down. Restarting the dev env fixes the problem.

Comment: Any other side effects... Any other keys (Left / right) stop working ?

Comment: @Rory None that are immediately apparent to me. When it happens again I will spend some time and investigate instead of going into HULK SMASH mode.

Comment: I've asked our support team to work with you so we can determine what is happening, if it is in fact CodeRush that is causing this, and how we can fix it ASAP. You can contact support directly at support@devexpress.com.

Comment: What version are you using? We just tried to test the latest 10.1.4 release and could not repro this behavior.

Comment: I am hitting the same problem as TheHurt in VS2010. All I have to do is close the tab and reopen and it is back to normal. I am also noting that when it goes into this mode, holding down the shift key causes the arrow keys to function properly until I release it again.

Comment: I've had this issue using Resharper, not CodeRush.  Ctrl-tab a few times fixes it.

Comment: I have been having this problem with the CTRL key (which does weird crap when you are typing and get a series of random menu commands.)  I just had the SHIFT key stick too, which finally prompt me to think it was actually VS and I found this.  Wow, how does this happen and not get fixed by MS?  The Ctrl-Tab thing worked for me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just had the same problem. I managed to put editor back in "normal" mode by Ctrl+Tab-ing to different tab and back.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: You just saved me one keyboard. :)

Comment: Yeah, saved me a keyboard too.  I just took a big whack at it and it did not fix, it was about to go through my monitor!

Comment: VS2010 just jammed almost half of my keyboard... Ctrl+Tab worked

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a known issue with VS2010. Some testers reported it back in the September 2010. It does not appear to be linked to CodeRush, but is in fact a Visual Studio bug.

However, Microsoft seem to have closed the bug as they couldn't replicate it in the lab. One work around seems to be to press ALT + Enter. Another suggests pressing Enter on the keypad.

Answer (score 1):

I think in all honesty that this is perhaps not the best place to do a proper bug investigation.

Perhaps consider opening a bug report in the DevExpress Support Center (http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).

I'm not suggesting that this be swept under a carpet either. You can provide a link to the Issue from this question and anyone needing similar information could then follow said link

It just seems to me that DevExpress' official support are better equipped to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Close your visual studio window and reopen your project again. Key will start working normally.

Answer (score 0):

mine does that to . I have windows 7 . The only way to get rid of that is to change your settings !! :p

Answer (score 0):

The culprit for me was "Clownfish" for Skype.

Ctrl-Shift hot keys are enabled by default.